# Code is running perfectly in the console but giving error: no rows to aggregate when knitting to pdf

Tags: r, knitr, aggregate-functions

Ques 3- Calculate the city wise spend on each product on the yearly basis.

df :

```
S.No. Country   Product     Year    Amount

1.     US        GOLD       2004    487330
2.     UK       SILVER      2005    345701
3.    RUSSIA   PLATINUM     2006    450000
4.    INDIA    PLATINUM     2004    439980
5.    FRANCE     GOLD       2005    546000
6.    FRANCE    SILVER      2004    320000
7.     UK        GOLD       2006    215000
```

The aggregate code I used is:

```
df <- aggregate(df$Amount, 
                by = list(Country = df$Country, Product = df$Product, Year = df$Year),
                FUN = sum)
```

---

It is something like this- df :

S.No.  Country    Product     Year    Amount

1. ```
     US        GOLD       2004    487330
   ```
2. ```
     UK       SILVER      2005    345701
   ```
3. ```
   RUSSIA    PLATINUM     2006    450000
   ```
4. ```
   INDIA     PLATINUM     2004    439980
   ```
5. ```
   FRANCE      GOLD       2005    546000
   ```

The aggregate code I used is:

df <- aggregate(df$Amount, by = list(Country = df$Country, Product = df$Product, Year = df$Year), FUN = sum)

Comment: A minimal working example would be nice. But if your code runs in the console and throws an error when you try to knit it to pdf, there is probably a variable missing that you have in your environment while using the console.

Comment: When running the R script again, it states that column- Amount(that has to be aggregated) does not exist. But when trying head() in the console, it is present.

Comment: could you create a minimal working example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I don't use aggregate, but it seems like the first argument should be an existing R object ...

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this before, which is when I understood that **the environment of your console is not the same as the environment used for knitting a Markdown file.**  You have not posted your entire .Rmd file (if you're knitting from a Markdown file), but I would guess that `df` is defined within your console, but not in the actual file.

Additionally, `df()` is defined as a function in R as `stats::df()` for the F distribution.  In the absence of the existence of a dataframe, `df`, the console will revert to using this.

Take the following example that you can try to illustrate the point I'm making:

- Create a dataframe in your console.  For example, `my_df <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)`.
- Open a new Markdown file and have a code in the file that just prints the dataframe: `print(my_df)`.
- Run the code chunk(s) in the markdown file, and everything will work fine.  It will seem like there's no issue at all.  If you're using Rstudio, you'll see the output of the `my_df` data frame printed in there.
- Knit the .Rmd file to... anything.  You'll get the following error: `Error in print(my_df) : object "my_df" not found...`

When you are running code chunks in the editor, it will run in the environment of your console.  When you knit the file, a separate environment is created.  Keep this in mind and then check - again, I'd bet that `df` is not defined in your file - you probably defined it in the console.

Comment: But even after renaming the dataframe as "expend", the same error.

Comment: expend <- inner_join(t1, t2, by = "Customer")
expend$M[grepl("04", expend$M)] <- "2004"
expend$M[grepl("05", expend$M)] <- "2005"
expend$M[grepl("06", expend$M)] <- "2006"

expend_agg <- aggregate(expend$A, by=list(C = expend$C, P = expend$P, M = expend$M), FUN=sum)